# fondo circular sobre icon dentro de un text input

Tags: html, css

Necesito crear un fondo con formato elíptico dentro de un `text input`, pero no lo estoy logrando hacer.

```
   .circle-icon {
    color:#fff;    
    background: #009640;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

y el HTML

```
<div class="input-group">
<input class="form-control rounded-pill py-2 pr-5 mr-1 bg-transparent" required type="text" name="search"
       placeholder="Buscar ...">
<span class="input-group-append">
    <div class="input-group-text border-0 bg-transparent ml-n5">
        <i class="lnr lnr-magnifier circle-icon"></i>
    </div>
 </span>
```

estos son mis resultados hasta ahora
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
y a esto debería llegar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

alguna idea? gracias de antemano

Comment: tal vez con un largo de mas de 30px

Answer (score 0):

En lugar de definir `width` y `height` prueba utilizando las siguientes propiedades:

- line-height: sustituye al height, dara la altura que necesitas centrando el texto verticalmente.
- padding: al definir el padding que ha de tener a los dados el texto estara en el centro. El border-radius deberia ser el mismo valor que el padding que uses horizontal para conseguir mas o menos lo que buscas

```
.circle-icon {
  color:#fff;    
  background: #009640;
  padding: 0 20px;
  line-height: 30px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
```

Comment: ahi queda con el formato que necesito, pero me queda la mitar afuera del input, alguna idea?